# Normalizing XML adjacency list model into HTML tree list

Tags: xslt

I've seen examples of transforming "adjacency model" XML but none that will do it quite right for a ul/li bullet list. Could someone give me a hint? It would be great if the solution could support typical adjacency model requirements and deal with multiple level nesting/recursion.

If the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <row Id="2" Name="data" />
  <row Id="3" Name="people" />
  <row Id="4" Name="person" ParentId="3" />
  <row Id="6" Name="folder" ParentId="2" />
  <row Id="7" Name="thing" ParentId="3" />
  <row Id="8" Name="web" />
  <row Id="9" Name="link" ParentId="8" />
</root>
```

And I use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
<ul id="someid" class="menu">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/row[not(@ParentId)]"/>
</ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
<ul>
    <li>
    <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@Id"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="rel">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//row[@ParentId=$ID]"/>
   </li>
</ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then I get:

```
<ul id="someid" class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li rel="2">
      data<ul>
        <li rel="6">folder</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li rel="3">
      people
      <ul>
        <li rel="4">person</li>
      </ul><ul>
        <li rel="7">thing</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li rel="8">
      web<ul>
        <li rel="9">link</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Note the extra close/open ul tags between the "person" and "thing" li's- shouldn't be there. I can see why it's happening but just not sure how to change the code to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's the list above but without the extra /ul ul tags between person and thing. I don't think that list is valid in HTML as long as those tags are there? i.e. the person and thing items are siblings and they are both children of the "people" item.

Comment: This does not make much difference to a browser, and it's correct. However you'll find in my answer the correct way to create a nested list.

Comment: :) thanks. Will verify and mark as answer ASAP.

Comment: You are welcome. I've tested it as XSLT 1.0 with MSXSL 4.5.

Comment: ...actually...I just realised that it only works for one hierarchical level :(. I should have included more detailed data :(. Now trying to figure out how to do more levels i.e. display an extra row such as <row Id="10" Name="anotherone" ParentId="9" />

Comment: @jqwha the question does not properly reflect your real use case. You need then a recursive approach I think. Feel free to expand your question if you are in trouble or, better, create a new question trying to include an input sample as close as possible to your real use case.

Comment: Hi @empo - I'll edit the above question to reflect the situation. This is early work so that was all the data I had :(. I made an assumption because I'm thinking about (and mentioned) the "adjacency" model which is typically used to support recursion and multiple nesting. I'll try to update it because I think this will be really useful - there just doesn't seem to be an answer out there!

Comment: Looks like the answer by @cordsen below does the trick nicely! Thank you both so much. Learning all the time here!!!

Comment: Ok, anyway, for the sake of correctness, I've updated my answer with a recrusive template which does the (HTML compliant) job. Cheers

Comment: Changed the title to match better the contents of the question. Feel free to revert to the original if you care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated to reflect OP new requests**

This is a recursive template which does an **HTML-compliant** nested list as deinfed in the W3C specs.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <ul id="someid" class="menu">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row[not(@ParentId)]"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <li rel="{@Id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
            <xsl:if test="count(../row[@ParentId=current()/@Id])>0">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../row[@ParentId=current()/@Id]"/>
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on this input:

```
<root>
  <row Id="1" Name="data" />
  <row Id="2" Name="data" />
  <row Id="3" Name="people" />
  <row Id="4" Name="person" ParentId="3" />
  <row Id="6" Name="folder" ParentId="2" />
  <row Id="7" Name="thing" ParentId="3" />
  <row Id="8" Name="web" />
  <row Id="9" Name="link" ParentId="8" />
    <row Id="10" Name="anotherone" ParentId="9" />
    <row Id="11" Name="anotherone" ParentId="9" />
    <row Id="12" Name="anotherone" ParentId="9" />
    <row Id="13" Name="anotherone" ParentId="3" />
</root>
```

Produces:

```
<ul id="someid" class="menu">
   <li rel="1">data</li>
   <li rel="2">data<ul>
         <li rel="6">folder</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li rel="3">people<ul>
         <li rel="4">person</li>
         <li rel="7">thing</li>
         <li rel="13">anotherone</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li rel="8">web<ul>
         <li rel="9">link<ul>
               <li rel="10">anotherone</li>
               <li rel="11">anotherone</li>
               <li rel="12">anotherone</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If you are in trouble about how list should be created, try them at [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists2).

Comment: OK - could everyone just STOP being awesome for a minute, I'm starting to feel stupid :)

Answer (score 2):

You are really close, you just need to move your `<xsl:variable name="ID" select="@Id"/>` and your `<xsl:apply-templates select="//row[@ParentId=$ID]"/>` outside of your `<ul>...</ul>` statement.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul id="someid" class="menu">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/row[not(@ParentId)]"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@Id"/>
      <li>
        <xsl:attribute name="rel">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      </li>
    <xsl:if test="//row[@ParentId=$ID]">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//row[@ParentId=$ID]"/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this produces the result I think you are looking for

```
<ul id="someid" class="menu">
  <li rel="2">data</li>
  <ul>
    <li rel="6">folder</li>
  </ul>
  <li rel="3">people</li>
  <ul>
    <li rel="4">person</li>
    <li rel="7">thing</li>
  </ul>
  <li rel="8">web</li>
  <ul>
    <li rel="9">link</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

this also removes the extra `<ul>` before the top level `<li rel="2">`

Comment: This output HTML really does not look like correct HTML, even if a  browser will display the list anyway.

Comment: @empo - I see what you mean - I was trying to deviate as little as possible from the OP's provided output, but the inner <ul> can be a child of <li> which is better form.

Comment: Works like a charm and handles the recursion (that I SHOULD have mentioned!!)

Comment: +1 for initial recursivity (not mentioned by the OP). About the wrong HTML you are not so far from the correct code.